# How come I cannot access the public enum of another class as a static field?

Tags: google-closure-library

I have an enum in a file:

```
goog.provide('animals.Fish');

animals.Fish = function(obj) {
  this.name_ = obj[animals.Fish.Properties.NAME];
  this.awesomenessLevel_ = obj[animals.Fish.Properties.AWESOMENESS];
}

/**
 * Public list of properties.
 * @enum {string}
 */
animals.Fish.Properties = {
  NAME: 'name',
  AWESOMENESS: 'awesomenessLevel',
}
```

How come I can't access this enum as a static field of Fish in another class like this?

```
goog.require('animals.Fish');
...
var tuna = new animals.Fish(
  animals.Fish.NAME: 'tuna',
  animals.Fish.AWESOMENESS: '100'
)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure enumeration types are based on the concept of [Enum Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) from languages such as Java and C++. In Java, enum types are defined as follows:

> An *enum type* is a type whose *fields* consist of a fixed set of constants. Common examples include compass directions (values of NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, and WEST) and the days of the week.

In your example above, `animals.Fish.Properties` should probably be represented as a [record type](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types), since the assigned values are not constants. In the example below, `animals.Fish.Properties` has been renamed `animals.Properties` so that it could be applied to any type of animal (not just fish).

### fish.js

```js
goog.provide('animals.Fish');
goog.provide('animals.Properties');


/** @typedef {{name: string, awesomeness: string}} */
animals.Properties;


/**
 * @param {animals.Properties} properties Animal properties.
 * @constructor 
 */
animals.Fish = function(properties) {
  /** @type {string} */
  this.name_ = properties.name;

  /** @type {string} */
  this.awesomenessLevel_ = properties.awesomeness;
};


/**
 * @return {string} The name of the fish.
 */
animals.Fish.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name_;
};
```

### animals_app.js

```
goog.provide('animals.app');

goog.require('animals.Fish');

animals.app.tuna = new animals.Fish({name: 'tuna', awesomeness: '100'});    
alert(animals.app.tuna.getName()); // alerts 'tuna'
```

On a side note, in the original example there should not be a comma after: `AWESOMENESS: 'awesomenessLevel'` in the definition of `animals.Fish.Properties`. In addition, in your second file you need to use the fully qualified enum name. So instead of `animals.Fish.NAME` it would be `animals.Fish.Properties.NAME`.